# variable representing type? inheritance at runtime?

Tags: c++, interface, types, runtime, mixins

My reason for asking the question:
I am using a large framework not of my own design. I need to use several "user information" classes which are unrelated as far as the code is concerned. They do not derive from any common base class, and I do not have access to the source code to recompile.

These information classes work like this: there are classes A, B, C, etc. These classes each have an information class, Ainfo, Binfo, etc. associated with them. Because the user (i.e. me) needs to attach different informations to a given object of a given class (meaning I might have two different classes deriving from Ainfo that I want to attach to an object of A), and there is only one information slot, I want to make an information object that can old other various information objects. That way, I can just add my information into this fake information-object-which-is-a-container-for-other-information-objects.

The problem arises in that I would like to do this for Ainfo, Binfo, Cinfo, Dinfo etc. So I would like to write a mixin or something that just adds the container functionality to any of the plain old info classes.

The problem is that the information classes Ainfo, Binfo, etc. require different constructor arguments.

So the question:

Is it possible to pass a vector of types into the constructor of the mixin? That way I could have a variable list of appropriate constructor parameters passed in? Can you assign a type to a variable outside of a template argument? Can you cast with this variable?

or

Is it possible to inherit from a specific object? Could I for example create a new Ainfo object using the correct constructor, then do the mixin on that specific object. This would be like the usage of the decorator pattern, except I have no common interface. (the object being decorated is the interface)

or

am I just going to have to bite the bullet and write 15,000 (exaggeration :) ) classes which are exactly the same, but inherit from a different base class and contain a different type of object?

Summary:

I need to add a container feature to several different classes while maintaining the interface of each class and utilizing their argument-taking constructors. I would like to not duplicate code.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for totally butchering terminology.

Comment: Honestly, C++ is a really bad choice of language for a trying to create classes at run-time.

Comment: Why not construct the `AllInfo` object, then add the ordinary info objects to it one at a time?

Comment: @Beta: Because I can only add an "Allinfo" object of the right type to the object it is describing. So, I could create an "Allinfo" object of the correct type for an A object, but could not add it to a B object. Do you mean create one class that inherits from all possible information objects, which stores void pointers to the actual information, then use that type as the container in all the different cases? Would I just have a gigantic constructor for the container? That might make too much overhead to have so many base objects floating around and generally unused.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about inheritance, no, I'm not talking about void pointers, no, I'm not talking about gigantic constructors. You want a class derived from `Ainfo` such that an instance of it can contain several instances of several classes derived from `Ainfo`, is that correct? And you want this for `Binfo` and `Cinfo` and so on with a minimum of redundant typing?

Comment: @Beta: Yes, that's what I want. I guess I just don't understand what you meant by your answer. Could you explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like what you want is a [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html). It's like a C++-style union. It is strongly typed (so that you always know what you actually stored in it), and it has a powerful visitation mechanism that makes it easy to map many different types to a single operation.

For example, you can do this:

```
typedef boost::variant<Ainfo, Binfo, Cinfo> CommonInfo;

//In a function.
CommonInfo someInfo = Ainfo();
```

You can then write visitor functors that can be used to call members of the info objects.

```
class DoThingInfoVisitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(Ainfo &info) {info.DoThing()}
    void operator()(Binfo &info) {info.DoThing2()}
    void operator()(Cinfo &info) {info.StepA(); info.StepB();}
};
```

Armed with this object, if you want to do whatever this DoThing means for any `CommonInfo` type:

```
CommonInfo someInfo = Ainfo();
boost::apply_visitor( times_two_visitor(), someInfo );
```

This will call the `Ainfo` version, since that's what happens to be stored in `someInfo`. If it had stored `Binfo`, then you could use that. You can build a suite of these visitors; they can return values, take parameters (though you'll need to store them in the functor), and various other tricks you can learn from the docs.

Comment: This sounds cool, but I don't understand how I could use it to add the container functionality. Could you elaborate? I need to take a *info and give it the ability to contain other *info's. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not doable in templates, and you can't hack it with the preprocessor, then you're gonna have to do it by hand. C++ doesn't contain any type manipulation at run-time, `typeid()` and `dynamic_cast` is all you've got.

Comment: can I cast using the type_info object returned by typeid()?

Comment: @user487100: No, you cannot cast using type_info objects.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of an oversimplification, but if nothing else it should help to clarify your question. Using templates, you can easily generate classes that derive from your info classes. The following classes illustrate this concept.

```
class Ainfo {
  std::string _a;
public:
  void setContent(const std::string& A);
  const char * print() const; // prints _a
};

class Binfo {
  std::string _b;
public:
  void setContent(const std::string& B);
  const char * print() const; // prints _b
};

template<class Tinfo>
class Info : public Tinfo {
};
```

You could then use this template as follows.

```
Info<Ainfo> my_info;
my_info.setContent("test");
std::cout << my_info.print();
```

**UPDATE:** If you also want to override the template's constructor, try using a member template.

```
template<class Tinfo>
class Info : public Tinfo {
public:
    template<typename arg>
    Info(arg rhs) : Tinfo(rhs) { }
};
```

Using this, you can compile and run the following.

```
Info<Ainfo> my_info("Testing...");
std::cout << my_info.print();
```

I could be wrong, but I have a feeling that we're getting pretty close now...

Comment: That's correct. This is what I meant when I said mixin. However, there is a problem in that Ainfo requires something other than a no-arg constructor, and this constructor has a different signature than Binfo. I guess this is an old question that I have just re-asked: how to do mixins with constructor arguments. I thought that some type of type or runtime magic might exist that could help me, or some other scheme that might better fit the situation.

Comment: By "when I said mixin" I meant, "based upon my understanding of the term mixin" (I am not a very knowledgeable programmer.)

Comment: @user487100 I updated my answer so that the `Info` template now generates constructors dynamically. If this doesn't answer your question, you'll have to narrow it down for me a bit more.  :)